# Copy directories, subdirectory and files from one server to another server in java

Tags: java

I have written a java code to copy all directories and files from one location to another location in the same machine and is working well. But, I am not sure how to copy all directories and files from one server to another server. Can someone help

Comment: How do you access the servers? Do they both have Samba-Shares?

Comment: Those are windows server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried so far?
How does your current logic look like?

Consider accessing a directory through the [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) Object by passing a directory, for example *C:\Source*. You could also create a File object with *\\server\Source* when the Source is located on server and is a network share.

Have a look at the documentation of the *File* object linked above to get further information. Don't forget to test whether the directory is available or not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your Windows Servers have Samba shares. So your target will look something like this
\192.168.100.111\share\target_dir

First make sure that you have the proper read/write rights on the shared folder. Then map the shared folder to a driveletter. You could take a look at this tutorial: http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsxpnetworking/ht/mapnetworkdrive.htm
The way you do it for other versions than XP is mostly the same.

Now you have a driveletter for your target share. So your target looks something like
x:\target_dir

This target can now be used within a java File object.

In addition you could use other libraries to access the samba share directly or use other shares, for example ftp.